# How can I select a Jenkins pipeline file from a branch specified in a build parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized Jenkins pipeline build.  One of the parameters (branch) is the branch to build.  The pipeline file is stored in the branch.

In the Pipeline definition, when I use `*/${branch}` as the branch to build in place of `*/main` the `${branch}` does not get replaced but shows up as a literal.  If I hard code the branch it works as expected.

The `${branch}` does get replaced as expected in the pipeline file.  So the `branch` parameter is being set.

Is there a way to get the parameter value into the "Pipeline script from SCM" retrieval from git?

Comment: could you paste you jenkinsfile so we can help you

Comment: The problem is not in the jenkinsfile it is in the Jenkins configuration that selects the jenkins file to use.  I want the jenkins to pull the jenkinsfile from a git branch.  However, I can not get the parameter to be interpreted by the jenkinsfile retrieval in the jenkins job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try another approach as following:

1. In pipeline configuration page, change pipeline from SCM to pipeline script
2. Put following pipeline script in input box

```
node('<Jenkins node label>') {
    
    properties([
        parameters([
            // parameter for branch
        ])
    ])
    
    git url: '', credentailId:'', branch: "${branch}"

    load '<relative path to your Jenkinsfile>'
}
```

Comment: Hi @yong, does this method have any limitation? `load` seem not design for such case I just wondering if it would break something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the branch parameter, when you disable the "Lightweight Checkout".
See [JENKINS-28447](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-28447)

Comment: The link doesn't seem right

Comment: Why it seems not right?
Please read the comments too.